# Confirm file type matches extention using PHP (problems with MS Word, Excel, and PowerPoint)

Tags: php, mime-types

Before accepting a file, I wish to confirm that the actual file matches the file extension.  to do so, I do the following:

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime=finfo_file($finfo, $filename);
$ext=getExtFromMime($mime); //Simple switch lookup table
if($ext==pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) {//File is okay}
else {//file is bad}
```

Other than my problems associated with Microsoft files, do you see any problems with this approach?

PHP finfo_file() used to provide the same mime "application/zip" type for MS Word 2007, Excel 2007, and PowerPoint 2007 files.  Then, PHP >= 5.3.11 and >= 5.4.1 changed the returned mime types from "application/zip" to the 2003 mimes

- application/msword
- application/vnd.ms-excel
- application/vnd.ms-powerpoint).

The correct mime types for these three file types, however, are as follows:

- application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
- application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
- application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation

How should I get the correct mime types for 2007 files so I can confirm they match their file type?

Comment: The problem is that people could still spoof the mime-types and the extension. You could open the file in binary mode, and check for certain bytes in certain locations to truly verify it's type.

Comment: @crush.   Doesn't file_info() do this?  Per http://php.net/manual/en/intro.fileinfo.php: The functions in this module try to guess the content type and encoding of a file by looking for certain magic byte sequences at specific positions within the file. While this is not a bullet proof approach the heuristics used do a very good job.

Comment: Seems you are right. The actual documentation page for finfo_file() makes no mention of this. You might have to do the byte checking on your own if PHP is automatically grouping them into a more generic mime type.